# Node.js How to get previous url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, express-session

I want to get previous url, for example in **all** my `/admin` routes I open a form where the admin needs to re-enter his password to get redirected to the route he requested, but the problem is after I validate his password and I try to redirect him to the route he initially requested, I don't have this route anymore, it's lost. For example, admin requests /admin/register, a form appears that posts to `validate-password`, and then if it finds that the password matches (correct password entered), it should redirect the user to the route he once requested, but I don't know how to get the initial route he requested

```
router.all('/admin/*', isAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('validatePassword', {message: 'Please re-enter your password to get access to ' + req.originalUrl});
    // next();
});

router.get('/admin/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register', {message: req.flash('message'), role_id: req.user.role_id})
});


// Validate password, admin re-enter password to get access to /admin routes
router.post('/validate-password', async (req, res, next) => {
    const password = req.body.password;
    const match = await passwordController.comparePassword(password, req.user.password);
    console.log(password);
    if (match) {
        // return res.redirect('/' +); HOW DO I REDIRECT HERE
        return next();
    } else {
        // return res.render('changePassword', {role_id: req.user.role_id});
        return res.render('validatePassword', {message: 'Wrong password'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Answer to this basically this same question done over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61023491/disable-middleware-when-redirecting/61024605#61024605) on their follow-on question which isn't really a different question.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you use cookies for or server-side sessions for (which also use a cookie).  You authenticate the user once, set a cookie and then on future requests from that browser, the cookie will be sent along with each request and you can then check that cookie to see if they are authenticated or not and decide what they are or aren't authorized to do based on that.  That's how nearly every site on the web that uses a login works.

I would recommend using the [`express-session` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) which creates a server-side session for you (and manages the cookie for it automatically for you) and then when the user is authenticated, you can set an auth flag in the session that all your routes that require auth can check.

You don't have to use express-session.  You can manage the cookie yourself, but then you'll have to make sure the cookie is properly encrypted (JWT is a popular library for that) so it can be easily forged by a rogue client.  And, any state you want to keep for the user will either have to be kept in the cookie itself (cookies should be kept not real large because they are sent back and forth on every http request and stored in the browser) or you would have to put an encrypted id in the cookie that you can use as a key to your own server-side session object.

---

**Edits added** after OP clarifies they are already using express-session.

It's common when redirected to login that you send a query string or hidden form element which is the original URL the user wanted to go to. Then, the login form will send that query string or hidden form element along with it's login form data to the server. After successfully logging in, the server then redirects you to the original target URL that the user wanted to go to. so, users goes to `/admin/add`, gets redirected to `/login`, but that login form contains a hidden form element `/admin/add`. User submits password form.

Server validates pwd, then gets original `/admin/add` url from the login form and redirects user to that URL. Your auth check for that sees that the user just logged in so they are allowed to proceed.

Comment: I'm already using express-session and storing a session ID cookie, I just want the already logged in admin to re-enter his password for more security in certain routes

Comment: @JohnnyBra - Well, then keep whatever state you need in the session on the previous route and check it there in the next route.  The session object is how you keep track of things for each user.  If all you want to know is last route, then just put that in the session and check it there.  I could have written a more targeted answer if you included that info in your question.

Comment: The problem I'm having is this: I have 2 routes /admin/add and /admin/register, both routes require the password to be re-entered, but now when I send the user to the validate password form when he requests any of these 2 admin routes, and he enters the password correctly, I have no way of knowing from what route he initially requested, di he request /admin/add or /admin/register?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @JohnnyBra - Well, it's common when redirected to login that you send a query string or hidden form element which is the original URL the user wanted to go to.  Then, the login form will send that query string or hidden form element along with it's login form data to the server.  After successfully logging in, the server then redirects you to the original target URL that the user wanted to go to.  so, users goes to `/admin/add`, gets redirected to `/login`, but that login form contains a hidden form element `/admin/add`.  User submits password form.

Comment: @JohnnyBra - Server validates pwd, then gets original `/admin/add` url from the login form and redirects user to that URL.  Your auth check for that sees that the user just logged in so they are allowed to proceed.

Comment: @JohnnyBra - Does this explain it to you now?

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
router.all('/admin/*', isAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('validatePassword', {message: 'Please re-enter your password to get access to ' + req.originalUrl});
    // next();
});
```

When you go to render this page, can you attach the original route as a local as you do with `message`?  You should be able to add `req.originalUrl` and pass it to `validatePassword`.  Then when that page calls the POST to validate the password, you pass the redirect URL up to that as part of the body.