# Disable middleware when redirecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a `isAdmin` middleware, and there's a page in my website where I want to disable this `isAdmin` middleware and let the user go to the page /admin/register, how can I disable the isAdmin middleware in a redirect?

```
return res.redirect('/admin/register');
```

Midlleware :

```
router.all('/admin/*', isAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('validatePassword', {message: 'Please re-enter your password to get access to ' + req.originalUrl, redirectRoute: req.originalUrl});
    // next();
});

router.get('/admin/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register', {message: req.flash('message'), role_id: req.user.role_id})
});
```

Comment: As I already explained in my answer to your your previous  question which you seem to have ignored, you need to set a property in your express-session object that tells your `validatePassword` function that it can skip prompting for the password because the user is already validate for the `/admin/register` route.  And, you probably want that to have a time value associated with it too so it's only good for a certain amount of time.  Then, after your `validatePassword()` function sees that value set in the session, it clears it so it goes back to requiring the password again up access.

Comment: What if you declare your `admin/register` route before the `admin/*`?

Comment: @MartinBuezas - Then, it NEVER requires authentication which is bad.

Comment: Another way to do this is to keep two levels of auth timeout.  The long timeout is continually refreshed as the user uses the site and will allow them to keep their login for 30 minutes of some significant amount of time.  The short timeout is what higher priority routes require and it's only good for a few minutes after the user logs.  Then, whenever the user logs in, the short timeout is refreshed and they will immediately pass `validateShortTimePassword()` and can get right into the admin routes without a reprompt. Everywhere else you use `validateLongTimePassword()` which allows more time.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, then this question is missing important information. Maybe you have it from the other question you mention.

Comment: @MartinBuezas - Yep, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022884/node-js-how-to-get-previous-url).   This question does not explain the whole problem, though it does mention skipping auth after the redirect and the rest of the problem is that they don't want to skip auth when it's not just after a specific redirect where they just verified auth.  I'm having general communication challenges with the author so I think I'm just going to give up as the OP doesn't seem to be taking any of my advice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is part of the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022884/node-js-how-to-get-previous-url) where the real problem is that you want to force authentication before certain admin routes and then after that auth is successful you want to redirect back to the admin route that was originally requested and when your Express handler processes that admin route, it needs to know that it doesn't need to force auth now because auth was just done.

My suggestion would be to use your Express session for that.

Here are the overall steps:

1. In your `/admin` routes, you create a middleware `checkAdminPassword()` that checks to see if the password has very recently been verified (more on this later).  If not, it redirects to a password page and prefills in that password page form in a hidden field, the original desired URL destination.
2. In the password processing route, you validate the password and you set into the express session object the time that you validated the route.
3. You then use the original user destination (that was included in the password form in a hidden field) to redirect the user back to their original destination after successful password verification.
4. Then, when the `/admin` route gets hit again, it calls the `checkAdminPassword()` middleware.  This time, that middleware looks in the session object and sees that the password was just verified, a few seconds ago.  Since it was just freshly verified, it doesn't prompt again and lets the user through to the admin route.

Here are a examples of some code in a couple of these pieces. Here, when this matches, it sets the verification in the session and sets the current time and then it redirects to the redirectTarget (hidden field from the form).

```
// Validate password, admin re-enter password to get access to /admin routes
router.post('/validate-password', async (req, res, next) => {
    const password = req.body.password;
    const match = await passwordController.comparePassword(password, req.user.password);
    console.log(password);
    if (match) {
        // set the time of last password verification
        req.session.passwordVerifiedTime = Date.now();
        res.redirect(req.body.redirectTarget).
    } else {
        // return res.render('changePassword', {role_id: req.user.role_id});
        req.session.passwordVerifiedTime = 0;
        // pass the target for redirection after successful password so this template
        // can insert that in a hidden field in the password form
        return res.render('validatePassword', {message: 'Wrong password', target: req.session.redirectAfterAuthUrl});
    }
});
```

Then, I'd get rid of the `router.all('/admin/*', ...)` route as you don't need that.  In any `/admin` route that you want this extra verification, you can just add middleware to that route or if you have a whole route of these routes, you can add the middleware just to the router.

```
router.get('/admin/register', checkAdminPassword, (req, res) => {
    res.render('register', {message: req.flash('message'), role_id: req.user.role_id})
});

function checkAdminPassword(req, res, next) {
    const adminPasswordExpiration = 30 * 1000;     // 30 seconds, you can set it to whatever you want
    const now = Date.now();
    if (req.session.passwordVerifiedTime && (now - req.session.passwordverified < adminPasswordExpiration)) {
        next();
    } else {
        // admin password verification either not set or expired
        // remember our desired target location
        req.session.redirectAfterAuthUrl = req.url;
        res.redirect("/validate-password");
    }
}
```

Comment: @johnnybra - I went to a lot of trouble to show you how to do this, but you've not responded at all in a day.  Does this help?  Does this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

Express uses the order you put your end points in to determine where to go. So going to /admin/register matches /admin/*, so Express uses that endpoint. If you switch the order of those two endpoints, it will go to the correct /admin/register function on your redirect.

```
 router.get('/admin/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register', {message: req.flash('message'), role_id: req.user.role_id})
});

 router.all('/admin/*', isAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('validatePassword', {message: 'Please re-enter your password to get access to ' + req.originalUrl, redirectRoute: req.originalUrl});
    // next();
});
```

Comment: This won't enforce password access on `/admin/register` at all which is not what the OP wants.  They want to require re-login, but then after the login, to let them in on a redirect.

Comment: Their question doesn't mention anything about requiring re-login. All they asked is how to disable the isAdmin on the /admin/register link. If they want to do something different, then they need to update the question to say what it is they actually need.

Comment: Yes, it is a poorly written question.  But, the key is that they only want to disable auth  only when redirecting from just doing auth.  The redirecting part is sort of in this question which your answer doesn't address.  The rest is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022884/node-js-how-to-get-previous-url) for earlier context.  Sorry you are caught in the cross-fire.